# Open Save As Dialog box using jQuery/Javascript after csv file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm trying to open save as dialog after user click a button but it takes to file to downloads folder. I want to prompt the user where to save the file.

Here is my Javascript function I have so far:

```
function exportOBCSerialsToCSV(e) {
    var dataSource = $("#vehicleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

    var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: dataSource.data(),
        filter: dataSource.filter()
    });

    filteredDataSource.read();

    var data = filteredDataSource.view();
    var result = '';

    for (var dataRow = 0; dataRow < data.length; dataRow++) {
        result += data[dataRow].OBCSerial + ',';
        if (dataRow == data.length - 1) {
            result += data[dataRow].OBCSerial;
        }
    }
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), 'OBC Serials.csv');
    }
    else if (window.URL != null) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        result = encodeURIComponent(result);
        a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + result;
        a.download = 'OBC Serials.csv';
        a.click();
    }
    else {
        window.open(result);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You will want to place an Input Type=file into your DOM.

Comment: Please could you give more details on how it's done. After clicking the download button I want to be prompted with the Save As Dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Below possibilities :

1. Set the header of the file on the server, like so:

```html
Below possibilities :

1. Set the header of the file on the server, like so:

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>

The download attribute does not allow you to change the filename or filetype any more as it is an obvious security risk.

What you are trying to do it replicate the right-click - save-as dialogue but I'm afraid that is not possible at this time.

2. When user's browser is set to automatically download all files in default location which is why not only this file but all other files from user's browser were downloaded directly without the save prompt dialogue. Changing the settings in browser to 'always ask the download location' can work.
```

The download attribute does not allow you to change the filename or filetype any more as it is an obvious security risk.
What you are trying to do it replicate the right-click - save-as dialogue but I'm afraid that is not possible at this time.

2. When user's browser is set to automatically download all files in default location which is why not only this file but all other files from user's browser were downloaded directly without the save prompt dialogue. Changing the settings in browser to 'always ask the download location' can work.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. I want to click download button and be prompted with the save as dialog box.